# Minimizing the mean square error

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

How do I minimize the mean square error of a weighted sum of two estimators?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $d_1$ and $d_2$ are supposed to be unbiased, $\mathbb E[d] = \theta$
and $E[(d - \theta)^2] = \text{Var}(d)$.  Since $d_1$ and $d_2$ are independent,
$$\text{Var}(\alpha d_1 + (1-\alpha) d_2) = \text{Var}(\alpha d_1) + \text{Var}((1-\alpha) d_2) = \alpha^2 \sigma_1^2 + (1-\alpha)^2 \sigma_2^2$$

Now, can you minimize that?

Comment: Why $d_1$ and $d_2$ are independent?

Comment: The original version of the question said they were.

Comment: Oh, really! Thank you!